# ln-service (npm-package) [ 400, 'ExpectedLndToCreateNewInvoice' ]

Tags: javascript, lightning-network

I'm using ln-service package and I'm connected to a local instance of lnd node (created with polar). I'm using plain js.

```
import lnservice from 'ln-service';


let lndz = lnservice.authenticatedLndGrpc({
    cert: tls,
    macaroon: adminMacaroon,
    socket: socket
})

try {
    let res = await lnservice.createInvoice({mtokens: "500", description: "new invoice", lnd:lndz})
} catch (error) {
    console.log("ERROR",error);
}
```

Error:

[ 400, 'ExpectedLndToCreateNewInvoice' ]

The only hint I'm getting from IDE is that `lndz` should have these fields, but I don't know what I should put in these fields, since it's not mentioned in the docs.

```
  autopilot: any;
  chain: any;
  default: any;
  invoices: any;
  router: any;
  signer: any;
  tower_client: any;
  tower_server: any;
  wallet: any;
  version: any;
```

What does 400 mean? How can I debug this? I looked at LND logs but no help there. How would I know what to put in those fields, since only 3 of the fields were mentioned

If I run a different method:

```
lnservice.getHeight(lndz)
```

I'm getting the correct block height, so it seems that I'm able to make a connection to the LND node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have to use object destructuring.

```
let {lnd} = lnservice.authenticatedLndGrpc({
    cert: tls,
    macaroon: adminMacaroon,
    socket: socket
})
```